# inputing negative numbers into a number reversal program

Tags: java

My program is supposed to take in random integers and reverse them. It currently works for all positive integers that are no more than ten digits long.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int input;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Its reversal is ");
        reverse(input);
        System.out.println();;
    }
    public static void reverse(int number) {
        if(number < 10 && number > 0) {
            System.out.println(number);
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(number % 10);
            reverse(number/10);
         }
    }   
}
```

I've been having trouble finding a way for the program to return the reversals of negative numbers. What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: So you want the minus sign at the end of the number then?

Comment: Please provide input and expectedoutput and describe the "Trouble"

Comment: no, the minus sign would still appear in the front

Comment: the recursion termination does not work in case of negative numbers, so the program will go into infinite loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the comments above, it looks like you want the reverse of -123 to be -321. If so, I think this code should work:

```
public static void reverse(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        System.out.print("-");
        reverse(number * -1);
    } else if (number < 10) {
        System.out.println(number);
    } else {
        System.out.print(number % 10);
        reverse(number / 10);
    }
}
```

(I dropped the `&& number > 0` because you had an infinite loop if the input is exactly `0`.)

---

Note: this code will give a `StackOverflowError` for `number == Integer.MIN_VALUE`, since `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. You can fix this as follows:

```
if (number < 0) {
  System.out.print("-");
  if (number == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    System.out.print(-(number % 10));
    number /= 10;
  }
  reverse(-number);
} else if ...
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a bunch. I was thinking about printing out the "-" but I didn't know how to carry on from there.

Comment: Super-nit: doesn't work correctly for `number == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, because `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1 > Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @smarx no - because `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE` - so you just keep calling `reverse` in the first branch.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you! I think I'll leave this code as-is, since no simple fix comes to mind, but it's nice to know this limitation.

Comment: @AndyTurner Interesting. Java doesn't throw an exception on the overflow?

Comment: @AndyTurner Just tried it myself. I'm surprised! Putting in a cheeky fix.

Comment: @smarx ok! I've just added a quick addendum to fix the MIN_VALUE case. Feel free to remove if you want to add your own.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method will help you

```
public static void reverse(int number) {
if (number < 10 && number > 0) {
  System.out.println(number);
  return;
} else if (number > 0) {
  System.out.print(number % 10);
  reverse(number / 10);
} else {
  System.out.print(number % 10);
  reverse((number / 10) * -1);
}
}
```

here we are printing the last element as a negative element, after that we are multiplying it with -1 so that the rest of the elements will be positive and positive loop will proceed form the second time.